# Postgresql function to create table with dynamic table name?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Let's say I have several users, each with their own set of contacts. Users get to select which 3rd parties have access to their contacts.

I could maybe create 1 large contact table and have an 'owner' column so that I can identify which contacts belong to which users. However, I'd then need to maintain row-level permissions so that I can restrict which 3rd parties do/don't have access to specific user contacts.

Instead, I think (and I could be mistaken here) it makes more sense to have a contact table for each user, e.g.: `contact_e878df81_eba1_4a61_b592_30ac7100362a`. I could then manage permissions in a separate table.

To create these 'dynamic contact tables', I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_contact_table(IN tbl_name text) RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
    table_name text;
BEGIN
    table_name = tbl_name;
    create table IF NOT EXISTS table_name
    (
        id serial  not null
            constraint test_pkey
                primary key,
        firstname varchar not null,
        lastname varchar not null,
        age int not null,
        address varchar not null,
        email varchar not null,
        created timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
    alter table table_name
        owner to postgres;
    RETURN 1;
END ;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute the function (`create_contact_table(contact_e878df81_eba1_4a61_b592_30ac7100362a)`, the table is created, but the name of the table is `table_name`...

Why is that? How can I fix it so that the table name is correct?

Comment: No, it's better to have a single table for all owners. Row-level permissions are typically used in controlled environment with a few users at most. But... you seems to be designing an app for many simultaneous users.

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: "*it makes more sense to have a contact table for each user*" - no, absolutely not. In fact it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @TheImpaler You meant table-level permissions, right?

Comment: "*I could then manage permissions in a separate table*" - you can still do that, if you want, when using row-level security policies.

Comment: @Bergi No, I meant row-level security. That is typically done by crafting a view filtering by the "current user" and forbidding access to the underlying tables.

Comment: @TheImpaler You mean one view per user, and each user gets a postgres role? I don't see how that's different from having a table per user. When you said "row-level permissions", I thought you meant [row security policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html), that are defined for a single table and actually *do* work well for many users.

Comment: @Bergi No, it's a single view in the database. However, the filtering condition in the `WHERE` clause includes a predicate with the "current user", with the form `WHERE my_table.username = CURRENT_USER`. That way, each separate account sees different rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only using `dynamic SQL`, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_contact_table(tbl_name text)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    v_sql text; 
    t1 text;
begin

    v_sql = '
    create table %I
    (
        id serial  not null
            constraint test_pkey
                primary key,
        firstname varchar not null,
        lastname varchar not null,
        age int not null,
        address varchar not null,
        email varchar not null,
        created timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
    ';
    
    raise notice 'SQL:: %', v_sql;

    EXECUTE format(v_sql, tbl_name);

    return true; 
          
END;
$function$
;
```